# Mongo aggregate query group using regex

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying write a script and get data from collections added in year and particular month.

And also get the records where 'Name' field matches my given regex.

Is it possible to use regex  group in aggregate? Something like this :

```
collection1.aggregate([
     {"$match": {"$expr":{"$and":[{"$eq":[{"$year":"$updated_time"}, year]}, {"$eq":[{"$month":"$updated_time"}, month]}]}}},
{$group : {_id : {"Name": {"$regex": '^ABC', "$options": "i"} },count: { $sum: 1 }}
}]
```

Or which is the best way to get it? how do i  modify this query to get count of regex match in that time frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$regex` inside the `$match` itself and then use [**`$count`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) to get the number of matched document

```
collection1.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$and": [
        { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$updated_time" }, year] },
        { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$updated_time" }, month] }
      ]
    },
    "Name": { "$regex": "^ABC", "$options": "i" }
  }},
  { "$count": "count" }
])
```

or either by [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) as well

```
collection1.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$and": [
        { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$updated_time" }, year] },
        { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$updated_time" }, month] }
      ]
    },
    "Name": { "$regex": "^ABC", "$options": "i" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you that works !! 
Had another query im trying to output the data to another collection by grouping as below : { "$group": {"_id": null,"count": { "$sum": 1 }},"updated_time":{ "$push": "$updated_time" }}, { "$out" : "new_Coll" }.. But this is adding updates times as per count value. I want update_time only once in new collection

Comment: It will add count and the update_time array nothing else

Comment: Yeah update_time is added multiple times if the count is 5 updated_time is added 5 times. Is my push statement incorrect ?

Comment: Yes it will add 5 time as the number of documents are also 5.

Comment: is it possible to add only once ?

Comment: Use `$first` instead of `$push` or even you want to set it as an array then use one more `$project` stage and slice the array